# 2 Different Templates for Django With Allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-1.4

I'm using Allauth with Django 1.4.

What I need to do is to create 2 different signup templates. The template HTML has to change, but it's basically the same displayed fields.

What I tried to do is to create a new URL with a new view. In this new view, I would simply create a variable like 'signup_form = "alternate_version"', return the original 'allauth.views.singup'. Then, in the template I would simply display something different based on this variable. So, this wouldn't be exactly 2 different templates, but this would fill my need.

Here's what I added in urls.py:

```
url(r'^abc/alternate-signup/?$','project.views.alternate_signup'),
```

In views.py, I added:

```
def alternate_signup(request):
    from allauth.account import views as account_views
    return account_views.signup
```

After that, I get that error:

```
'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

Any idea how to do that or any alternative you can think of?

Comment: I'm not very clear on what you're trying to do, but right now you're returning the function signup, not the view. try `return account_views.signup()` or `return account_views.signup(request)` if it takes the requests parameter, which it probably does

Comment: I already overrode the template file with a new layout. But, I need 2 different layouts of the signup page. Let's say one at /accounts/signup and one at /abc/signup. The URL are different, but the layout will also be different. Using a 'pre-view' method will allow me to set a varialbe in it, so that I can use it in the already overrode template to display the appropriate layout based on the URL.